# How does the omp ordered clause work?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

```
vector<int> v;

#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic, anyChunkSizeGreaterThan1)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            ...
            ...
            ...
#pragma omp ordered
            v.push_back(i);
    }
```

This fills `v` with an `n` sized ordered list.

When reaching the `omp ordered` block all threads need to wait for the lowest iteration possible thread to finish, but what if none of the threads was appointed that specific iteration? Or does the OpenMP runtime library always make sure that the lowest iteration is handled by some thread?

Also why is it suggested that `ordered` clause be used along with the `dynamic schedule`? Would `static schedule` affect performance?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `ordered` clause works like this: different threads execute concurrently until they encounter the `ordered` region, which is then executed sequentially in the same order as it would get executed in a serial loop. This still allows for some degree of concurrency, especially if the code section outside the `ordered` region has substantial run time.

There is no particular reason to use `dynamic` schedule instead of `static` schedule with small chunk size. It all depends on the structure of the code. Since `ordered` introduces dependency between the threads, if used with `schedule(static)` with default chunk size, the second thread would have to wait for the first one to finish all iterations, then the third thread would have to wait for the second one to finish its iterations (and hence for the first one too), and so on. One could easily visualise it with 3 threads and 9 iterations (3 per thread):

```
tid  List of     Timeline
     iterations
0    0,1,2       ==o==o==o
1    3,4,5       ==.......o==o==o
2    6,7,8       ==..............o==o==o
```

`=` shows that the thread is executing code in parallel. `o` is when the thread is executing the `ordered` region. `.` is the thread being idle, waiting for its turn to execute the `ordered` region. With `schedule(static,1)` the following would happen:

```
tid  List of     Timeline
     iterations
0    0,3,6       ==o==o==o
1    1,4,7       ==.o==o==o
2    2,5,8       ==..o==o==o
```

I believe the difference in both cases is more than obvious. With `schedule(dynamic)` the pictures above would become more or less random as the list of iterations assigned to each thread is non-deterministic. It would also add an additional overhead. It is only useful if the amount of computation is different for each iteration and it takes much more time to do the computation than is the added overhead of using dynamic scheduling.

Don't worry about the lowest numbered iteration. It is usually handled to the first thread in the team to become ready to execute code.

Comment: @Cookie503, note that if the chunk size is too small, then caching might become less useful because of lost data locality. This might hurt your performance much worse than the implied serialisation. Experiment with different chunk sizes until the best speed-up is achieved. Use `ordered` loops wisely and if possible evade them, even if it leads to increased memory footprint - e.g. (given your particular example) a simple preallocated array (or other thread-safe random access container) should be used instead of a vector: `arr[i] = i;`

Comment: Incase of a chunk size which is too small, are we looking at the risk of false sharing incase the data lies in the same cache line?

Comment: @WajdanAli it depends on the data types and their arrangement, but one indeed tends to run into false sharing problems more often with smaller chunks than with larger ones.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use the syntax?