# Reduction with OpenMP

Tags: openmp

I am trying to compute mean of a 2d matrix using openmp. This 2d matrix is actually an image.

I am doing the thread-wise division of data. For example, if I have `N` threads than I process Rows/`N` number of rows with `thread0`, and so on.

My question is: Can I use the openmp reduction clause with "`#pragma omp parallel`"?

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction( + : sum )
{
    if( thread == 0 )
       bla bla code 
       sum = sum + val;

    else if( thread == 1 )
       bla bla code
       sum = sum + val;
}
```

Comment: The short answer is YES!  Even though most of the tutorials only show the example of `reduction` append on the `parallel for` clause. But `reduction` on the `parallel` clause is also correct and some times useful.

Answer (score 35):

Yes, you can - the reduction clause is applicable to the whole parallel region as well as to individual `for` worksharing constructs. This allows for e.g. reduction over computations done in different parallel sections (the preferred way to restructure the code):

```c
#pragma omp parallel sections private(val) reduction(+:sum)
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
      bla bla code
      sum += val;
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
      bla bla code
      sum += val;
   }
}
```

You can also use the OpenMP `for` worksharing construct to automatically distribute the loop iterations among the threads in the team instead of reimplementing it using sections:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for private(val) reduction(+:sum)
for (row = 0; row < Rows; row++)
{
   bla bla code
   sum += val;
}
```

Note that reduction variables are private and their intermediate values (i.e. the value they hold before the reduction at the end of the `parallel` region) are only partial and not very useful. For example the following serial loop cannot be (easily?) transformed to a parallel one with reduction operation:

```c
for (row = 0; row < Rows; row++)
{
   bla bla code
   sum += val;
   if (sum > threshold)
      yada yada code
}
```

Here the `yada yada code` should be executed in each iteration once the accumulated value of `sum` has passed the value of `threshold`. When the loop is run in parallel, the private values of `sum` might never reach `threshold`, even if their sum does.

Comment: If he calls ordered with that kind o distribution he loose most of the parallelism.

Comment: @dreamcrash, if implemented correctly, ordered execution might not kill most of the parallelism - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13230816/1374437).

Comment: Exactly, we must not use the static for with the default chunk size.

Comment: In the second case if instead of a reduction on a sum, e.g with `reduction(+:...`, it was to find the minimum or maximum, e.g with `reduction(min:...`, one could do it manually using double-checked locking and it work work fine.

Comment: @Miszy, the edit reason you've specified is invalid. Neither `shared(Rows)` nor `private(row)` is _required_ by the OpenMP standard. `row` is the loop counter and as such has predetermined data sharing class of `private`. `Rows` is declared outside the parallel region and as such has a predetermined sharing class of `shared`.

Comment: It's not required _per se_ but it's a matter of a good style to add them. If you look at any of OpenMP examples (including the one for this reduction clause) they all have explicit `shared` and `private`

Comment: @Miszy Would you start adding `default(none)` to all StackOverflow code just because it is "good style"?

Comment: @VladimirF, I added the `default(none)` clause because listing all variables in the respective clauses makes sense only if done in combination with `default(none)`.

Comment: @HristoIliev It was just to point out that the original edit didn't make sense. I actually didn't notice you added that, I thought you reverted the edit, I was only looking to the history.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `sum = sum + val` could interpreted as `val[i] = val[i-1] + val[i]` in 1-d array (or `val[rows][cols] = val[rows][cols-1] + val[rows][cols]` in 2-d array) which is a [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) calculation.

Reduction is one of solution for prefix sum, you can use reduction to any commutative-associative operators like '+', '-', '*', '/'.

Comment: How is `-` and `/` commutative-associative?

Comment: 1 - 2 = 1 + (-2) = (-2) + 1.... 1/5 = 1 * (0.2) = (0.2) * 1