# Openmp pragma barrier for calculating pi in

Tags: c, openmp

I have a program in .C that uses openmp that can be seen below; the program is used to compute pi given a set of steps; however, I am new to openMp, so my knowledge is limited.

I'm attempting to implement a barrier for this program, but I believe one is already implicit, so I'm not sure if I even need to implement it.

Thank you!

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4
static long num_steps = 100000000;
double step;

int main()
{
    int i;
    double start_time, run_time, pi, sum[NUM_THREADS];
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    step = 1.0 / (double)num_steps;

    start_time = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel 
    {
        int i, id, currentThread;
        double x;
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        currentThread = omp_get_num_threads();
        for (i = id, sum[id] = 0.0; i < num_steps; i = i + currentThread)
        {
            x = (i + 0.5) * step;

            sum[id] = sum[id] + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
        }
    }

    run_time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
    //we then get the value of pie 
    for (i = 0, pi = 0.0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pi = pi + sum[i] * step;
    }
    printf("\n pi with %ld steps is %lf \n ", num_steps, pi);
    printf("run time = %6.6f seconds\n", run_time);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks plausible. What's the problem?

Comment: Your code has a performance issue due to false sharing and is unnecessarily complicated. One of the main advantages of OpenMP is that there is no need for manual reduction.

Comment: There is an implicit barrier at the end of the section. As for the reduction mentioned by Laci, consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290245/reduction-with-openmp for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there is no need for an explicit barrier, there is an implicit barrier at the end of the parallel section.

Your code, however, has a performance issue. Different threads update adjacent elements of `sum` array which can cause [false sharing](http://www.nic.uoregon.edu/%7Ekhuck/ts/acumem-report/manual_html/multithreading_problems.html):

> When multiple threads access same cache line and at least one of them
> writes to it, it causes costly invalidation misses and upgrades.

To avoid it you have to be sure that each element of the `sum` array is located on a different cache line, but there is a simpler solution: to use [OpenMP's reduction clause](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html). Please check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290245/reduction-with-openmp) suggested by @JeromeRichard. Using reduction your code should be something like this:

```
    double sum=0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_steps; i++)
    {
        const double x = (i + 0.5) * step;
        sum += 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
    }
```

Note also that you should use your variables in their minimum required scope.