# OpenMP generate segfault in Rcpp code for the SEIR model

Tags: c++, r, openmp, rcpp, armadillo

I wrote a (probably-inefficient, but anyway..) Rcpp code using inline to simulate a stochastic [SEIR model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SEIR_model).
The serial version compiles and works perfectly, but since I need to simulate from it a large number of times and since it seems to me like an embarrassingly parallel problem (just need to simulate again for other parameter values and return a matrix with the results) I tried to add  `#pragma omp parallel for` and to compile with `-fopenmp -lgomp` but ... boom!
I get a segfault even for very small examples!
I tried to add `setenv("OMP_STACKSIZE","24M",1);` and values well over 24M but still the segfault happens.

I'll explain briefly the code since it's a bit long (I tried to shorten it but the result change and I can't reproduce it..):
I have two nested loops, the inner one execute the model for a given parameter set and the outer one changes the parameters.

The only reason a race condition might happen is if the code were trying to execute set of instructions inside *inner* the loop in parallel (which cannot be done because of the model structure, on iteration `t` it depends on iteration `t-1`) and not to parallelize the *outer*, but if I'm not mistaken that is what the `parallel for` constructor does for default if put just outside the outer...

This is basically the form of the code I'm trying to run:

```
mat result(n_param,T_MAX);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0,i<n_param_set;i++){
    t=0;
    rowvec jnk(T_MAX);

    while(t < T_MAX){

        ...

        jnk(t) = something(jnk(t-1));

        ...

        t++;
    }

    result.row(i)=jnk;
}
return wrap(result);
```

And my question is: How I tell the compiler that I just want to compute in parallel the outer loop (even distributing them statically like n_loops/n_threads for each thread) and not the inner one (which is actually non-parallelizable)?

The real code is a bit more involved and I'll present it here for the sake of reproducibility if you're really willing, but I'm only asking about the behavior of OpenMP. Please notice that the only OpenMP instruction appears at line `122`.

```
library(Rcpp);library(RcppArmadillo);library(inline)

misc='
#include <math.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES 

#include <omp.h>

using namespace arma;

template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
  return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}


uvec rmultinomial(int n,vec prob)
{  
  int K = prob.n_elem;
  uvec rN = zeros<uvec>(K);
  double p_tot = sum(prob);
  double pp;

  for(int k = 0; k < K-1; k++) {
    if(prob(k)>0) {
      pp = prob[k] / p_tot;
      rN(k) = ((pp < 1.) ? (rbinom(1,(double) n,  pp))(0) : n);
      n -= rN[k];
    } else
      rN[k] = 0;
    if(n <= 0) /* we have all*/
      return rN;
    p_tot -= prob[k]; /* i.e. = sum(prob[(k+1):K]) */
  }
  rN[K-1] = n;
  return rN;
}
'

model_and_summary='
mat SEIR_sim_plus_summaries()
{
  vec alpha;
  alpha << 0.002 << 0.0045;
  vec beta;
  beta << 0.01 << 0.01;
  vec gamma;
  gamma << 1.0/14.0 << 1.0/14.0;
  vec sigma;
  sigma << 1.0/(3.5) << 1.0/(3.5);
  vec phi;
  phi << 0.8 << 0.8;
  int S_0 = 800;
  int E_0 = 100;
  int I_0 = 100;
  int R_0 = 0;
  int pop = 1000;
  double tau = 0.01;
  double t_0 = 0;
  vec obs_time;
  obs_time << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 8 << 9 << 10 << 11 << 12 << 13 << 14 << 15 << 16 << 17 << 18 << 19 << 20 << 21 << 22 << 23 << 24;

  const int n_obs = obs_time.n_elem;
  const int n_part = alpha.n_elem;
  mat stat(n_part,6);

//#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int k=0;k<n_part;k++) {    
    ivec INC_i(n_obs);
    ivec INC_o(n_obs);

// Event variables
    double alpha_t;
    int nX; //current number of people moving
    vec rates(8);
    uvec trans(4); // current transitions, e.g. from S to E,I,R,Universe
    vec r(4);  // rates e.g. from S to E, I, R, Univ.


/*********************** Initialize **********************/
    int S_curr = S_0;
    int S_prev = S_0;
    int E_curr = E_0;
    int E_prev = E_0;
    int I_curr = I_0;
    int I_prev = I_0;
    int R_curr = R_0;
    int R_prev = R_0;
    int IncI_curr = 0;
    int IncI_prev = 0;
    int IncO_curr = 0;
    int IncO_prev = 0;

    double t_curr = t_0;

    int t_idx =0;
    while( t_idx < n_obs ) {

// next time preparation
      t_curr += tau;

      S_prev = S_curr;
      E_prev = E_curr;
      I_prev = I_curr;
      R_prev = R_curr;
      IncI_prev = IncI_curr;
      IncO_prev = IncO_curr;

/*********************** description (rates) of the events **********************/
      alpha_t = alpha(k)*(1+phi(k)*sin(2*M_PI*(t_curr+0)/52)); //real contact rate, time expressed in weeks

      rates(0) = (alpha_t * ((double)I_curr / (double)pop ) * ((double)S_curr));   //e+1, s-1, r,i    one s get infected (goes in E, not yey infectous)
      rates(1) = (sigma(k) * E_curr);                               //e-1, i+1, r,s   one exposed become infectous (goes in I) INCIDENCE!!
      rates(2) = (gamma(k) * I_curr);                               //i-1, s,e, r+1    one i recover
      rates(3) = (beta(k) * I_curr);                                   //i-1, s, r,e        one i dies
      rates(4) = (beta(k) * R_curr);                                       //i,e, s, r-1        one r dies
      rates(5) = (beta(k) * E_curr);                                         //e-1, s, r,i      one e dies
      rates(6) = (beta(k) * S_curr);                                //s-1 e, i ,r   one s dies
      rates(7) = (beta(k) * pop);                                              //s+1    one susc is born



// Let the events occour
/*********************** S compartement **********************/
      if((rates(0)+rates(6))>0){
        nX = rbinom(1,S_prev,1-exp(-(rates(0)+rates(6))*tau))(0);

        r(0) = rates(0)/(rates(0)+rates(6)); r(1) = 0.0; r(2) = 0; r(3) = rates(6)/(rates(0)+rates(6)); 
        trans = rmultinomial(nX, r);

        S_curr -= nX;
        E_curr += trans(0);
        I_curr += trans(1);
        R_curr += trans(2);
//trans(3) contains dead individual, who disappear...we could avoid this using sequential conditional binomial

      }

/*********************** E compartement **********************/
      if((rates(1)+rates(5))>0){

        nX = rbinom(1,E_prev,1-exp(-(rates(1)+rates(5))*tau))(0);

        r(0) = 0.0; r(1) = rates(1)/(rates(1)+rates(5)); r(2) = 0.0; r(3) = rates(5)/(rates(1)+rates(5)); 
        trans = rmultinomial(nX, r);

        S_curr += trans(0);
        E_curr -= nX;
        I_curr += trans(1);
        R_curr += trans(2);

        IncI_curr += trans(1);
      }

/*********************** I compartement **********************/
      if((rates(2)+rates(3))>0){
        nX = rbinom(1,I_prev,1-exp(-(rates(2)+rates(3))*tau))(0);

        r(0) = 0.0; r(1) = 0.0; r(2) = rates(2)/(rates(2)+rates(3)); r(3) = rates(3)/(rates(2)+rates(3)); 
        trans = rmultinomial(nX, r);

        S_curr += trans(0);
        E_curr += trans(1);
        I_curr -= nX;
        R_curr += trans(2);

        IncO_curr += trans(2);
      }

/*********************** R compartement **********************/
      if(rates(4)>0){
        nX = rbinom(1,R_prev,1-exp(-rates(4)*tau))(0);

        r(0) = 0.0; r(1) = 0.0; r(2) = 0.0; r(3) = rates(4)/rates(4); 
        trans = rmultinomial(nX, r);

        S_curr += trans(0);
        E_curr += trans(1);
        I_curr += trans(2);
        R_curr -= nX;
      }

/*********************** Universe **********************/
      S_curr += pop - (S_curr+E_curr+I_curr+R_curr); //it should be poisson, but since the pop is fixed...


/*********************** Save & Continue **********************/
// Check if the time is interesting for us
      if(t_curr > obs_time[t_idx]){
        INC_i(t_idx) = IncI_curr;
        INC_o(t_idx) = IncO_curr;
        IncI_curr = IncI_prev = 0;
        IncO_curr = IncO_prev = 0;

        t_idx++;
      }

//else just go on...

    }

/*********************** Finished - Starting w/ stats **********************/

// INC_i is the useful variable, how can I change its reference withour copying it?
    ivec incidence = INC_i; //just so if I want to use INC_o i have to change just this...

//Scan the epidemics to recover the summary stats (naively divide the data each 52 weeks)
    double n_years = ceil((double)obs_time(n_obs-1)/52.0);
    vec mu_attack(n_years);
    vec ratio_attack(n_years-1);
    vec peak(n_years);

    vec atk(52);
    peak(0)=0.0;
    vec tmpExplo(52); //explosiveness
    vec explo(n_years);

    int year=0;
    int week;

    for(week=0 ; week<n_obs ; week++){   

      if(week - 52*year > 51){
        mu_attack(year) = sum( atk )/(double)pop;

        if(year>0)
          ratio_attack(year-1) = mu_attack(year)/mu_attack(year-1);

        for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
          if(atk(i)>(peak(year)/2.0)){
            tmpExplo(i) = 1.0;
          } else {
            tmpExplo(i) = 0.0;
          }
        }
        explo(year) = sum(tmpExplo);

        year++;
        peak(year)=0.0;
      }

      atk(week-52*year) = incidence(week);
      if( peak(year) < incidence(week) )
        peak(year)=incidence(week);

    }

    if(week - 52*year > 51){
      mu_attack(year) = sum( atk )/(double)pop;
    } else {

      ivec idx(52);
      for(int i=0;i<52;i++)
        { idx(i) = i; } //take just the updated ones...
      vec tmp = atk.elem(find(idx<(week - 52*year)));

      mu_attack(year) = sum( tmp )/((double)pop * (tmp.n_elem/52.0)); 
      ratio_attack(year-1) = mu_attack(year)/mu_attack(year-1);

      for(int i=0;i<tmp.n_elem;i++){
        if(tmp(i)>(peak(year)/2.0)){
          tmpExplo(i) = 1.0;
        } else {
          tmpExplo(i) = 0.0;
        }
      }
      for(int i=tmp.n_elem;i<52;i++)
        tmpExplo(i) = 0.0; //to reset the others
      explo(year) = sum(tmpExplo);

    }

    double correlation2;
    double correlation4;
    vec autocorr = acf(peak);


/***** ACF *****/
    if(n_years<3){
      correlation2=0.0;
      correlation4=0.0;
    } else {
      if(n_years<5){
        correlation2 = autocorr(1);
        correlation4 = 0.0;
      } else {
        correlation2 = autocorr(1);
        correlation4 = autocorr(3);
      }
    }

    rowvec jnk(6);
    jnk << sum(mu_attack)/(year+1.0)
        << (sum( log(ratio_attack)%log(ratio_attack) )/(n_years-1)) - (pow(sum( log(ratio_attack) )/(n_years-1),2))
        << correlation2 << correlation4 << max(peak) << sum(explo)/n_years;

    stat.row(k) = jnk;

  }

  return stat;
}
'


main='
std::cout << "max_num_threads " << omp_get_max_threads() << std::endl;

RNGScope scope;

mat summaries =  SEIR_sim_plus_summaries();

return wrap(summaries);
'

plug = getPlugin("RcppArmadillo")

## modify the plugin for Rcpp to support OpenMP
plug$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS <- paste('-fopenmp', plug$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS)
plug$env$PKG_LIBS <- paste('-fopenmp -lgomp', plug$env$PKG_LIBS)

SEIR_sim_summary = cxxfunction(sig=signature(),main,settings=plug,inc = paste(misc,model_and_summary),verbose=TRUE)

SEIR_sim_summary()
```

Thanks for the help!

NB: before you ask, I slightly modified the Rcpp multinomial sampling function just because I liked that way more than the one using pointer...not any other particular reason! :)

Comment: try to reduce the problem to something reproducible / readable in < 2 minutes.

Comment: I see calls to functions like `rbinom` and `rmultinomial`; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967763/set-rng-state-with-openmp-and-rcpp for details on why this won't work as you expect.

Comment: If you call back to R from your OpenMP portions, don't be surprised if your code explodes. R is **not** multithreaded or re-entrant.

Comment: @KevinUshey, `rbinom` and `rmultinomial` works in the serial version, with the parallel one I don't get the chance to see if they behave strangely..

@DirkEddelbuettel This is not what my code does. After having the results computed (in parallel), the master thread should return to R a matrix.

Comment: Note that `OMP_STACKSIZE` controls only the stack size for the additional OpenMP threads. It does not affect the stack size of the master thread. Perhaps you should use `ulimit -s ...` if you suspect that the stack is the problem and you run on Unix-like OS.

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev, but if I run the code serially I don't get the segfault, so the problem arise either from a stack overflow due to one of the additional threads (unlikely) or more probably from a race condition I cannot seem to control.
How can I tell the program I want to run the whole loop-iteration in parallel on more threads and not allow him to try and parallelize a single iteration?

Comment: The inner loop is no way parallelised. It could be that the pseudo-random generator is not thread-safe, i.e. calling `rnorm` or any other PRNG from several threads at the same time might corrupt a shared state structure and lead to the crash. Enable the saving of core files `ulimit -c unlimited` and add `-g` to the compile options. Then examine the core file with `gdb` to see where the segfault occurs.

Comment: Also note that `stat.row(k) = jnk;` might be unsafe. I don't know how matrices and vectors are implemented in Rcpp, but you might try to put this statement inside an OpenMP `critical` construct. If Armadillo shares its matrix implementation code with Scythe, then that line of code is definitely not thread-safe and must be guarded by a critical section.

Comment: Look at [the Rcpp Gallery posts on OpenMP](http://gallery.rcpp.org/tags/openmp/) and notice how these posts do not use R data structures inside critical sections.  Multithreading and R just do not mix as we already told you.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks, the PRNG was indeed the problem! By substituting each random draw with his expectation the code run flawlessly!! Thanks again!
If you could put your comment as an answer I'll accept it! ;)
Now the question is how to use RNG _and_ OpenMP, I guess I shoud just switch to something which is not R-based to draw the samples as Dirk suggested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core pseudo-random number generators (PRNGs) in R are not designed to be used in multithreaded environments. That is, their state is stored in a static array (`dummy` from `src/main/PRNG.c`) and therefore is shared among all threads. Moreover several other static structures are used to store states for the higher-level interfaces to the core PRNGs.

A possible solution could be that you put each call to `rnorm()` or other sampling functions inside named critical sections with all having the same name, e.g.:

```cpp
...
#pragma omp critical(random)
rN(k) = ((pp < 1.) ? (rbinom(1,(double) n,  pp))(0) : n);
...
if((rates(0)+rates(6))>0){
   #pragma omp critical(random)
   nX = rbinom(1,S_prev,1-exp(-(rates(0)+rates(6))*tau))(0);
...
```

Note that the `critical` construct operates on the structured block following it and therefore locks the entire statement. If a random number is being drawn inline inside a call to a time-consuming function, e.g.

```
#pragma omp critical(random)
x = slow_computation(rbinom(...));
```

this is better transformed to:

```
#pragma omp critical(random)
rb = rbinom(...);
x = slow_computation(rb);
```

That way only the `rb = rbinom(...);` statement will be protected.

Comment: Thank again, I'd just like to point out for future viewer that even though this solution worked in the end I switched to boost::random and followed this solution to make it works!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504264/boost-random-and-openmp

Cheers,M