# OpenMP ordered clause

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

How is the ordered clause in OpenMP supposed to be correctly used? There is this test code to check if the loop will be executed by increasing values of n but it is not always the case.

Did I misinterpret the definition of the ordered clause?

> The ordered construct specifies a structured block in a loop region
>   that will be executed in the order of the loop iterations. This
>   sequentializes and orders the code within an ordered region while
>   allowing code outside the region to run in parallel.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <omp.h>

    int main(){

        int n;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
        {
    #pragma omp for ordered
            for (n=0;n<10;n++)
                printf("n = %d\n",n);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

When compiling with

```
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -fopenmp test_par.c
```

The output is

```
    ./a.out 
    n = 0 
    n = 1 
    n = 2 
    n = 9 
    n = 3 
    n = 4 
    n = 5 
    n = 6 
    n = 7 
    n = 8
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OpenMP `ordered` clause is supposed to be used in two distinct stages:

1. As a clause of the `for` directive, to indicate some possible ordering of iterations; and then
2. As a standalone directive to indicate which parts of the statements inside the loop are to be kept ordered.

So in essence, your example should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(){

    int n;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for ordered
        for (n=0;n<10;n++)
            #pragma omp ordered
            printf("n = %d\n",n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives:

```
$ g++ -fopenmp order.cc
$ ./a.out 
n = 0
n = 1
n = 2
n = 3
n = 4
n = 5
n = 6
n = 7
n = 8
n = 9
```

However, two remarks here:

1. This parallel loop is actually fully sequentialised as there is nothing outside of the `ordered` directive
2. Moreover, if you which to mitigate the impact of serialisation induced by the `ordered` directive, you should play with the `schedule` directive. A good candidate for an "effective" scheduling in the case of an ordered loop would be a `schedule( static, 1 )` for example.

And finally, Hristo Iliev explains it all better than I'll ever be able to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230816/5239503)