# Does an OpenMP ordered for always assign parts of the loop to threads in order, too?

Tags: c++11, openmp

### Background

I am relying on OpenMP parallelization and pseudo-random number generation in my program but at the same I would like to make the results to be perfectly replicable if desired (provided the same number of threads).

I'm seeding a `thread_local` PRNG for each thread separately like this,

```
{
  std::minstd_rand master{};
  #pragma omp parallel for ordered
  for(int j = 0; j < omp_get_num_threads(); j++)
    #pragma omp ordered
    global::tl_rng.seed(master());
}
```

and I've come up with the following way of producing `count` of some elements and putting them all in an array at the end in a *deterministic* order (results of thread 0 first, of thread 1 next etc.)

```
std::vector<Element> all{};
...
#pragma omp parallel if(parallel)
{
  std::vector<Element> tmp{};
  tmp.reserve(count/omp_get_num_threads() + 1);

  // generation loop
  #pragma omp for
  for(size_t j = 0; j < count; j++)
    tmp.push_back(generateElement(global::tl_rng));

  // collection loop
  #pragma omp for ordered
  for(int j = 0; j < omp_get_num_threads(); j++)
    #pragma omp ordered
    all.insert(all.end(),
        std::make_move_iterator(tmp.begin()),
        std::make_move_iterator(tmp.end()));
}
```

### The question

**This seems to work** but I'm not sure if it's reliable (read: portable). Specifically, if, for example, the second thread is done with its share of the main loop early because its `generateElement()` calls happened to return quick, won't it technically be allowed to pick the first iteration of the collecting loop? In my compiler that does not happen and it's always thread 0 doing `j = 0`, thread 1 doing `j = 1` etc. as intended. Does that follow from the standard or is it allowed to be compiler-specific behaviour?

I could not find much about the `ordered` clause in the `for` directive except that [it is required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5b5b6eb.aspx) if the loop contains an [`ordered` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3f31k66.aspx) inside. Does it always guarantee that the threads will split the loop from the start in increasing `thread_num`? Where does it say so in referrable sources? Or do I have to make my "generation" loop `ordered` as well – does it actually make difference (performance- or logic-wise) when there's no `ordered` directive in it?

Please don't answer by experience, or by how OpenMP would *logically* be implemented. I'd like to be backed by the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the code in its current state is not portable. It will work only if the default loop schedule is `static`, that is, the iteration space is divided into `count / #threads` contiguous chunks and then assigned to the threads in the order of their thread ID with a guaranteed mapping between chunk and thread ID. But the OpenMP specification does not prescribe any default schedule and leaves it to the implementation to pick one. Many implementations use `static`, but that is not guaranteed to always be the case.

If you add `schedule(static)` to *all* loop constructs, then the combination of `ordered` clause and `ordered` construct within each loop body will ensure that thread 0 will receive the the first chunk of iterations and will also be the first one to execute the `ordered` construct. For the loops that run over the number of threads, the chunk size will be one, i.e. each thread will execute exactly one iteration and the order of the iterations of the parallel loop will match those of a sequential loop. The 1:1 mapping of iteration number to thread ID done by the `static` schedule will then ensure the behaviour you are aiming for.

Note that if the first loop, where you initialise the thread-local PRNGs, is in a different parallel region, you must ensure that both parallel regions execute with the same number of threads, e.g., by disabling dynamic team sizing (`omp_set_dynamic(0);`) or by explicit application of the `num_threads` clause.

As to the significance of the `ordered` clause + construct, it does not influence the assignment of iterations to threads, but it synchronises the threads and makes sure that the physical execution order will match the logical one. A statically scheduled loop without an `ordered` clause will still assign iteration 0 to thread 0, but there will be no guarantee that some other thread won't execute its loop body ahead of thread 0. Also, any code in the loop body outside of the `ordered` construct is still allowed to execute concurrently and out of order - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230816/1374437) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Perfect. I upvoted the other answer you reference here earlier today, actually. I was just unsure about the following, which seems to be implied there and confirmed further by what you wrote here: so the meaning of the `ordered` clause for the enclosing `for` directive is nothing but to *mark* that an `ordered` directive *may* appear inside it, and makes no difference to the loop whatsoever if the latter does not happen?

Comment: Exactly. The directive makes the loop execution as ordered as it usually requires a different runtime function to support ordered loops. Which part of the loop body should be synchronised is declared using the construct. And indeed, since the `for` construct might be orphaned in, e.g., some external library code, the compiler cannot reliably determine whether a loop is ordered or not by just looking for the presence of the `ordered` construct in the body, even if the full call graph is examined.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that may be the case but was confused by G++ requiring that the ordered construct "be closely nested inside a loop region with an ‘ordered’ clause", which I would interpret as precluding being in separate functions or even farther (if that's what was meant by orphaning).

Comment: Hm, that's true and it's what the specification demands. Then it was probably to ease the parser in the earlier OpenMP versions.