# OpenMP on fortran 90 lasts almost the same(if not more) as non parallelized program

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a simulation of an Ising 2D model to get some expected values as a function of the temperature of the system. For L=48, the one-threaded version takes about 240 seconds to run 20 temperatures and 1 seed each, but the parallelized version takes about 268 seconds, which is similar.

If you take the time per seed per temperature, it results in 12 seconds for the one-threaded version and 13.4 seconds for the parallelized version. I'm looking for help with my code because I don't understand these durations. I thought that the parallelized version would split one temperature among all threads and therefore should take about 30 seconds to complete.

I need to run the simulation for 50 temperatures and 200 seeds each, for 5 values of L. It would be helpful to reduce the compute time, because otherwise it could take 20 hours for L=48 and some days for L=72.

I'm using an i7-10700KF (8 cores, 16 logical threads).

```
program Ising
    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    integer L, seed, i, j, seed0, nseed,k
    parameter (L=48)
    integer s(1:L, 1:L)
    integer*4 pbc(0:L+1), mctot, N, mcd, mcini, difE
    real*8 genrand_real2, magne, energ, energia, temp, temp1, DE
    real*8 mag, w(-8:8)
    real*8 start, finish
    real*8 sum, sume, sume2, summ, summ2, sumam, vare, varm, maxcv, maxx
    real*8 cv, x, Tmaxcv, Tmaxx
    integer irand, jrand

11  format(10(f20.6))

! Initialize variables

    mctot = 80000
    mcd = 20
    mcini = 8000
    N = L*L
    seed0 = 20347880
    nseed = 20
    maxcv=0.d0
    maxx=0.d0

! Initialize vector pbc

    pbc(0) = L
    pbc(L+1) = 1
    do i = 1, L
        pbc(i) = i
    end do

! Initialize matrix s with random values

    do i = 1, L
        do j = 1, L
            if (genrand_real2() < 0.5) then
                s(i,j) = 1
            else
                s(i,j) = -1
            endif
        end do
    end do

! Metropolis algorithm

    open(1, file='Expectation values.dat')
    start = omp_get_wtime()
    write(1,*) '#Temp,       ','E,       ','E2,       ','M,       ','M2,       ','|M|,       ','VarE,       ','VarM,       ',&
    'Cv,       ','X,       '

!Start loop to calculate for different temperatures
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(s,seed,w,energia,difE,irand,jrand,temp,mag,sum,sume,sume2,summ,summ2,sumam,vare,varm,cv,x) 
        temp1 = 1.59d0
!$OMP DO ordered schedule(dynamic)
    do k = 1, 10
        temp = temp1 + (0.01d0*k)
!Define the matrix w, which contains the values of the Boltzmann function for each temperature, so as not to have to calculate them each iteration

        do i = -8, 8
            w(i) = dexp(-i/temp)
        end do
        write(*,*) "Temperature: ", temp, "Thread", omp_get_thread_num()
        sum = 0.d0
        sume = 0.d0
        sume2 = 0.d0
        summ = 0.d0
        summ2 = 0.d0
        sumam = 0.d0

        do seed = seed0, seed0 + nseed-1, 1
            call init_genrand(seed)
            call reinicia(s,l)
            energia = energ(s,l,pbc)

            do i = 1, mctot
                do j = 1, N
                    irand = int(genrand_real2()*L) + 1
                    jrand = int(genrand_real2()*L) + 1
                    difE = int(DE(s,l,irand,jrand,pbc))
                    if (difE < 0) then
                        s(irand,jrand) = -s(irand,jrand)
                        energia = energia + difE
                    else if (genrand_real2() < w(int(difE))) then
                        s(irand,jrand) = -s(irand,jrand)
                        energia = energia + difE
                    endif
                end do

                if ((i > mcini).and.(mcd*(i/mcd)==i)) then
                    mag= magne(s,l)
                    sum = sum + 1.d0
                    sume = sume + energia
                    sume2 = sume2 + energia**2
                    summ = summ + mag
                    summ2 = summ2 + mag**2
                    sumam = sumam + abs(mag)
                endif
            end do
        end  do

!Energy
        sume=sume/(sum*N)
        sume2=sume2/(sum*N*N)
!Magnetitzation
        summ = summ/(sum*N)
        sumam=sumam/(sum*N)
        summ2=summ2/(sum*N*N)
!Variances
        vare = dsqrt(sume2-sume*sume)/dsqrt(sum)
        varm = dsqrt(summ2-summ*summ)/dsqrt(sum)
!Cv
        cv = (N*(sume2-sume*sume))/temp**2
        if (cv.gt.maxcv) then
            maxcv=cv
            Tmaxcv=temp
        endif
!X
        x = (N*(summ2-summ*summ))/temp
        if (x.gt.maxx) then
            maxx=x
            Tmaxx=temp
        endif

        write(1,11) temp,sume,sume2,summ,summ2,sumam,vare,varm,cv,x
    end do
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

    finish = omp_get_wtime()
    close(1)

    print*, "Time: ",(finish-start),"Seconds"

end program Ising



! Functions

!Function that calculates the energy of the matrix s

real*8 function energ(S,L, pbc)
    implicit none
    integer s(1:L, 1:L), i, j, L
    integer*4 pbc(0:L+1)
    real*8 ene
    ene = 0.0d0
    do i = 1, L
        do j = 1, L
            ene = ene - s(i,j) * s(pbc(i+1),j) - s(i,j) * s(i,pbc(j+1))
        end do
    end do
    energ = ene
    return
end function energ

!Function that calculates the difference in energy that occurs when the spin of position (i, j) is changed

real*8 function DE(S,L,i,j,pbc)
    implicit none
    integer s(1:L, 1:L), i, j, L, difE
    integer*4 pbc(0:L+1)
    real*8 suma
    difE = 0
    suma = 0.0d0
        suma = suma + s(pbc(i-1),j) + s(pbc(i+1),j) + s(i,pbc(j-1)) + s(i,pbc(j+1))
        difE = difE + int(2 * s(i,j) * suma)
    DE = difE
    return
end function DE

!Function that calculates the magnetization of the matrix s

real*8 function magne(S,L)
    implicit none
    integer s(1:L, 1:L),L
    magne = sum(s)
    return
end function magne





! SUBRUTINES

!Subroutine that resets the matrix s with random values
subroutine reinicia(S,L)
    implicit none
    integer s(1:L, 1:L), i,j,L
    real*8 genrand_real2
    do i = 1, L
        do j = 1, L
            if (genrand_real2() < 0.5) then
                s(i,j) = 1
            else
                s(i,j) = -1
            endif
        end do
    end do
    return
end subroutine
```

I have tried parallelizing the seeds loop instead of the temperatures, but it lasts almost the same, so i think i'm not parallelizing it correctly, because it looks a nice code to parallelize.

The other option I thought of is to manually parallelize the simulation. I could do this by compiling 16 programs, each of which handles a different range of temperatures. Then I could run all of the programs concurrently, so each program would get its own thread. However, this approach would require a lot of extra RAM.

Comment: Welcome, it is good to take the [tour]. At least `sum` is not `private` so leads to a race condition. I suggest `default(none)`.

Comment: You're right, `sum` had to be private because it is independent for every temperature.

Comment: Why `Do Ordered`? That's essentially a serialised loop - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224155/how-does-the-omp-ordered-clause-work . Unless I am missing something you are observing exactly how I would expect this code to behave, the same speed as without opennMP, maybe slightly slower due to overheads. Oh, and real*8 is not fortran, and has never been part of Fortran, learn about Fortran kinds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: But why, if one thread takes one temperature and one seed and needs about 12 seconds to finish, why it takes 12*16 seconds if I use 16 threads and give one temperature and one seed to each thread? Aren't they computing at the same time? I think it should take almost 12 seconds too.

Comment: And if I do what I said at the end of the question (manually split the program), it takes what it should, about 12 seconds per temperature per seed.

Comment: You are using `Do Ordered`. This seralises the threads. Please read the link I gave - Quoting "The ordered clause works like this: different threads execute concurrently until they encounter the ordered region, which is then executed sequentially in the same order as it would get executed in a serial loop". This loop is essentially running one iteration after the other, with each thread waiting for the previous thread to finish an iteration. That's what `Do Ordered` *does*. You will have to get rid of ordered to parallelise this. I haven't analysed how easy that is.

Comment: OK, presumably you want ordered to get the results in the "right" order in the output file. So rather than writing straighaway save them in an array and write them in the order you want once the parallel region is done. And then get rid of ordered (and I suggest forget you ever knew it, its use is so rare in OMP). And I also *strongly* recommend default(none) as Vladimir suggests, getting rid of real*8/integer*4 and turning it into standard Fortran, sticking all subroutines in a module to get automatic argument checking, and I'm also worried whether your random number generator is thread safe.

Comment: Yes, the genrand generator probably is not thread-safe as it does not take a thread number argument. There are good parallel PRNGs suitable for Monte-Carlo available.

Comment: @IanBush There is no `omp ordered` directive inside the `omp do ordered` loop, so here the different threads do execute concurrently

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I was wrong - no time now but I now need to read what `do ordered` does. Strange construct name.

Comment: OMP DO ordered is a problem. I would 1) place "if (cv>... to write " in a critical region; 2) include i,j,k and sum1 (sum) as private; 3) use default (none) (so declare SHARED (temp1,seed0,nseed,pbc,mctot,N,mcini,mcd) );  4) remove "ordered"; 5) change sum to sum1 6) is genrand_real2 an intrinsic ? confirm it is threadsafe or get a threadsafe RNG and 7) remove temp1=1.59d0 from !$OMP.    The efficiency of this code is very dependent on the efficiency and effectiveness of genrand_real2 as thread-safe !