How to combine OMP section and for
Basically I have a parallel loop that has a couple inherently serial variables that I pre-calculate. However I want to be able to set off a given iteration of the for loop once it's serial variables are calculated.
Essentially I want something like this:
int num_completed = 0;
int serial_values[100];
#pragma omp parallel
{
    if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            serial_values[i] = i;
            num_completed++;
        }
    }

#pragma omp for
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        while(true){
            if(j < num_completed)
                break;
        }
        int serial = serial_values[j]
        do parallel loop
    }
}

This does work, but the for loop allocates work to thread 0, even though it's tied up doing the serial calculations. Mostly that means it is slower  because thread 0 has to calculate its share of the parallel loop in addition to the serial variables.
Also I know the spin lock isn't great but I couldn't think of anything better off the top of my head, if you have suggestions I'd welcome those too.
I've already tried using #pragma omp single nowait and it functions the same way. I've also tried #omp section but each section is meant to be executed by a single thread, not in parallel.

I don't follow.  If you have serial work to perform, then why are you doing it in a parallel section?  If that work needs to be performed before the thread group does other work, then how does the example code achieve that?  Or if you mean that you just want thread zero to perform different work from all the others, then what's wrong with simply putting the parallel for loop in an else block?

@JohnBollinger The reason the serial loop is in the parallel section is because once it calculates the first variable the first iteration of the parallel loop can run, second serial variable second parallel iteration etc. (the parallel sections are slower than the serial sections so it would still be faster). Putting it in an else section, the for loop still allocates work to thread 0, except now thread 0 never reaches it and it hangs indefinitely.

It's unclear what you think are gaining by separating out the so-called serial computations into a separate thread.  From the example code, I gather that there is a particular one of the serial_values required by each iteration of the parallel loop, so why not just compute those in the parallel loop?

@JohnBollinger That's what the while loop (spin lock) is for. It holds each iteration of the for loop until the serial loop has updated the num_completed counter.  It's inherently impossible to compute serial data in a parallel manner, that's what serial means. I can put an actual serial algorithm (like the Fibonacci sequence) in the serial loop if that would make it clearer.

You can serialize the computations with use of essentially the same spin lock without putting them in their own thread.

I don't think I know how I would do that. Can you give an example?

The problem sounds like a reasonable use case for using tasks. Your "serial" loop would create a task for each of the values. The other threads execute the tasks and implicitly execute the iterations of your for loop.

You are already using a spin lock to make the threads in the parallel loop wait for the serial computation to proceed far enough.  One way to move forward would be to leverage that, plus OpenMP scheduling parameters, to make the threads in the parallel loop perform the serial computation.  That might look something like this:
int num_completed = 0;
int serial_values[100];

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(monotonic:static, 1)
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    int serial;

    while (1) {
        if (j == num_completed) {
            // serial computation:
            serial = j
            serial_values[j] = serial;

            num_completed += 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // do parallel loop
}

The schedule(monotonic:static, 1) is relatively important here, because it ensures that the iterations of the parallel loop are split among the threads in single-iteration chunks, and that each thread executes its assigned chunks in logical iteration order.  You could also use schedule(monotonic:dynamic) or, equivalently, schedule(monotonic:dynamic, 1).  With chunks larger than one iteration, you could have threads delayed unnecessarily long (and that may be an issue for your original code).  With chunks executed out of order, you would likely get deadlocks on those spin locks.


I've also tried #omp section but each section is meant to be executed by a single thread, not in parallel.

Yes, but you can put a nested parallel region inside one of the sections.  I think this would probably be inferior to the approach described above, but it could yield a structure more similar to your original code.  Something like this, for example:
int num_completed = 0;
int serial_values[100];

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                serial_values[i] = i;
                num_completed++;
            }
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for schedule(monotonic:static, 1)
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                while (true) {
                    if (j < num_completed) break;
                }
                int serial = serial_values[j]

                // do parallel loop ...
            }
        }
    }
}

You can put a num_threads() clause on that parallel for loop too, if you like.

With this approach, the thread executing the "serial" part will not do anything once finished with it's part.

@Joachim, I assume you mean the second alternative presented in this answer.  In the first alternative, there is no thread dedicated to the serial part.  In any case, yes, I take that to be what the OP asked for: one thread performs all the serial computations then is done, while the other threads perform parallel computation as the needed serial data become available.

The first approach is a complete OpenMP anti pattern. The whole while loop should be replaced by an ordered region. How ordered works is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230816/8136338

Please feel free to write your own answer, @Joachim.  For what it's worth, I agree that the whole spin-lock thing is nasty, but that's what the OP started with and asked to make work.

Aren't atomic pragmas needed to update and test num_completed?

The approach based on ordered regions as suggested by @Joachim looks appropriate here:
int serial_values[100];
#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(static,1)
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    #pragma omp ordered
    {
        serial_values[i] = i;
    }

    int serial = serial_values[i]
    //do parallel stuff
}

An omp ordered directive is similar to a omp critical: it can be executed by only one thread at a time, but in addition the iteration i has to be executed before the iteration j if i<j. You don't even need the num_completed variable.
The scheme here will be the following with 4 threads:
Thread0: S0->P0-------->S4->P4-------->S8->P8-------->
Thread1:     S1->P1-------->S5->P5-------->
Thread2:         S2->P2-------->S6->P6-------->
Thread3:            S3->P3-------->S7->P6-------->

There can be no overlap between the serial parts because they are protected in an ordered region. At the beginning of the execution some threads are inactive, but there's no way to avoid that.
If you have a lot of iterations, then using larger chunks can help.
This approach is less efficient if the time spent in the serial part is "important" and/or if there are a lot of threads.

A task based solution seems somewhat easier; something like this
/*
 * An example solution using tasks for the StackOverflow question 
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78978654/how-to-combine-omp-section-and-for/
 */
#include <omp.h>

static problem()
{
#define PROBLEM_SIZE 100            /* A literal in the original :-( */
#define CHUNK_SIZE     7            /* As an example that doesn't divide
                                     * the problem size, to show why 
                                     * some of the code is needed. */
  
  int serial_values[PROBLEM_SIZE];
#pragma omp parallel
  {
#pragma omp single nowait
    {
      int lastBase = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < PROBLEM_SIZE; i++) {
        serial_values[i] = compute_serialValue(i);
        
        if ((i == PROBLEM_SIZE-1) || ((i%CHUNK_SIZE) == CHUNK_SIZE-1)) {
#pragma omp task
          {
            for (int j=lastBase; j<=i; j++) {
              int serial = serial_values[j];
              doParallelComputation(j, serial);
            }
          }
          lastBase = i+1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Obviously the size of the chunks is a tuning issue.
